# Go to #div box JavaScript

Tags: html, anchor

Maybe jQuery, maybe not, but how do i do so like when you click on a link eg. FAQ it goes to the FAQ div box? I mean if its on the bottom then you just click on that link and then it goes to it..

Wikipedia have it..
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USA
The links in the "Contents".. when you click you get to it..

Comment: Would someone with editing power please re-tag this question?  It's not about jQuery.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That's not Javascript, those are anchor links.  See: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html

Basically, you'd link as such:

```
<a href="#FAQ">FAQ</a>
```

Then above the content you're linking to:

```
<a name="FAQ" />
```

Alternatively, you could use the same link and set the ID of the FAQ section header to "FAQ", like so:

```
<h1 id="FAQ">FAQs</h1>
```

Answer (score 6):

First, add an id to the HTML element. This will serve as the anchor.

For example:

```
id="mybox"
```

Now simply add a link to **#mybox** on that page. E.g. **example.com/index.html#mybox**

```
<a href="#mybox">Box</a>
```

As mentioned these are not anything to do with javascript; it is not required for this.