# Go To div Box With Anchor - My Anchors Have Predefined href

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, anchor

Please see this thread: 
[Jump To div Box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255388/go-to-div-box-javascript)
How do I do it so when you click on a link? e.g. FAQ it goes to the FAQ div box?
I mean if its on the bottom then you just click on that link and then it goes to it.
For the answer we can refer to that link...

I have a new situation in asp.net with C#!
I have some links like below :

```
<a href="Dafault.aspx?path=...">File Name</a>
```

Those links cause postback and after postback I want to jump to a specific div!
How can I do that ?
Should I use javascript or jquery for doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution may help:

[Move to an anchor after an ASP.Net Postback](http://forums.asp.net/t/1311972.aspx)

But I would do a partial page update instead of full postback!

Answer (score 0):

Put your faq contents inside a `div` with `id="faq"` and define an anchor tag with `href="#faq"`. When the user clicks on the `anchor`, will be taken to the `div` whose id is faq.

Example:

```
<a href="#faq">Click here to go to the faq</a>
```

When the user clicks on the anchor above, will be taken right to the section where the `div` with `id=faq` is defined.

```
<div id="faq">
1. Question 
2. Question 
3. Question 
4. Question 
5. Question 
6. Question 
7. Question 
8. Question 
9. Question 
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for answer -> but i can not change my anchors href to #faq / their href is like "Dafault.aspx?path=..." and i need their codes during postbacks / what can i do after postback?

Comment: No need to, append the #faq to them, it will work without breaking your existing hrefs

Comment: @MoonLight because `#` are fragment identifiers and browsers are not supposed to send them to the server side. Read up: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier

Comment: dear Icarus : did you read my answer carefully -> your answer was like that link in my question -> but here we have another situation -> the other answer is my answer , not yours.plz give me some explain for understanding.

Comment: @MoonLight no need, what matters is that you solved the issue.