# Html page does not redirect for different location hash value

Tags: html, anchor

In my page, I have a site menu using the anchor:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="/default.aspx#map">Map</a></li>
  <li><a href="/default.aspx#doc">Document</a></li>
</ul>
```

And in the `default.aspx` I will check the `hash` of the current location to load the right value.

However I found that it does not work as expected.

For example, the current page url is `http://server/default.aspx`

Then I click the `doc` link, it does not redirect.

But if I change the url to `http://server/default.aspx#doc` and hit the `refresh` button, I will be redirected to the document page.

What is the problem?

---

BTW, this menu is not only used in the page of `default.asxp` but also other pages. So I can not use the `<li><a href="#map">Map</a></li>`.

So I am not using the simple anchor links, I use javascript to determine what content to be loaded by the `hash` of the `location`.

Comment: if you just want to redirect to an ID within your page you can just put `#map` as href attribute

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2255418/1763929).

Comment: @ToonCasteele:See my update.

Comment: I think as your page is not being refreshed, your javascript funciton is not being called when your # in the url changes.

Comment: What the hell is going on? I just found out there is an answer who tell me to use the `?` instead of `#`, and it worked. But now, where is the answer?

Comment: hahaha it was me, I deleted the answer when I thought you want to use javascript only so thought my answer is out of subject. I undeleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the # means that you're linking to somewhere in the page, so the link will never refresh the page at the place the browser will try to find an `<a name="what_is_after_the_hash"></a>` and take you to it. if you want to refresh the page you'll have to use ? at the place of # and then get your variables as query strings.

Comment: That's right. I use the javascript to get the variables and then determine the to be loaded content. The `?` works.