# How do I anchor my html index?

Tags: html, indexing, anchor

I am trying to create an anchor on my home page so that when someone navigates to my website, he directly jumps to the middle of the page (instead of defaulting to the top of the page). Any tips on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Possible duplicat http://stackoverflow.com/a/2255418/1763929

Comment: possible duplicate of [Go to #div box JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255388/go-to-div-box-javascript)

Comment: He wants to jump to the middle of the page on page load, not when clicking within the page. Should leave open.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have an anchor in the URL like www.yourdomain.com/#middleofpage, you will need to do this in javascript:

Check out the [scrollTo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.scrollTo?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/window.scrollTo) function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.scrollTo( x-coord, y-coord )
</script>
```

If you want 50% down the page, you could calculate like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var pageSize = (document.body.scrollHeight - document.body.clientHeight); 
    window.scrollTo(0,Math.ceil(pageSize/2);
</script>
```

Comment: There's no JavaScript tag.

Comment: That's been added.  Sorry assumed they would know.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="index.html#idOfSectionToJumpTo">Link</a>
```

Comment: there is no link, i want it to jump to the middle of the page when some one navigates to the page in the browser.