# jQuery scroll to next section without id or class

Tags: jquery, button, scroll, jquery-animate, sections

I'm just trying to build a simple walk-through website. My options are very basic, I have either an accept button or decline button in each  where players are sent to the next section or previous section.

**This is where I am:**

```
$( 'button.accept' ).click(function() {

var newSection = $('section').offset().top;

    // Scroll
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: newSection
    },5000, 'easeInOutSine');

    return false;
});
```

**This is what I tried already:**

```
var section = $('section').next().offset().top;
```

This basically takes me to the first section no matter what section I am in.

**This is what works:**

```
$( 'button.accept' ).click(function() {

var newSection = $('section-2').offset().top; //Different class on each <section>

    // Scroll
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: newSection
    },5000, 'easeInOutSine');

    return false;
});
```

The last is good but I'm adding unnecessary classes to my 's. How can I modify this to go to next or previous section with a button regardless of class or id.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think this is answer to your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255388/go-to-div-box-javascript

Comment: Why are they "unnecessary" classes? There is another way that you could do this without classes - you can get the index of each section and use that, but is that worth the effort when adding a handful of classes works?

Comment: @JayBlanchard So there is no way to tell jQuery, I am clicking a button in section-1 now move to section-2 without needing an identifier. I would have thought it would be like get next sibling or something.

Comment: If all of the sections are the child of a parent element you could use sibling functions like `next()` and `prev()`. But we don't have an example of the markup or a fiddle, so we can only guess.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I see what you are saying. I had already added classes to the sections so I guess I can go with that. Thanks for your help!